# How can I find groups of consecutive items in a python list?

Tags: python

I have a sorted list like this `[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,14]`

I have looked up different similar solutions but they dont provide help in my case

I want this list to output like this
`[ [1,4], [6,10], [12], [14] ]`
so basically a list of lists with a start and an end of a sequence.
Honestly looks very easy but i am kind of stuck on it right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Your question is vague. What are the criteria for forming the sub-lists?

Comment: there are no criteria tbh, just has to output exactly like mentioned in question.
so if there is a continious sequence, we only append beggining and the end of it, if there is no sequence, we just append a list with a single number in it

Comment: You can use https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups for this @a.lex.n !

Answer (score 8):

You can use [more_itertools.consecutive_groups](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups) for this available at https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/

```
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups

#Get the groupings of consecutive items
li = [list(item) for item in consecutive_groups([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,14])]
#[[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [12], [14]]

#Use the result to get range groupings
result = [ [item[0],item[-1]] if len(item) > 1 else [item[0]] for item in li]

print(result)
#[[1, 4], [6, 10], [12], [14]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution can look like this

```py
def make_ranges(l: list):
    prev = l[0]
    start = l[1]
    res = []
    for v in l[1:]:
        if v - 1 != prev:
            if start == prev:
                res.append([start])
            else:
                res.append([start, prev])
            start = v
        prev = v
    if l[-1] - 1 == l[-2]:
        res.append([start, l[-1])
    return res
```

For example:

```py
print(make_ranges(list(range(10)) + list(range(13, 20)) + [22]))
```

This code will print `[[0, 9], [13, 19], [22]]`

Comment: this is very close! however its not yet correct.
for example for arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
the output will be ```[[1], [1, 4], [6, 7]]```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the standard `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,14]

result = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda x: x[0] - x[1]):
    g = list(map(lambda x: x[1], g))
    if len(g) > 1:
        result.append([g[0], g[-1]])
    else:
        result.append([g[0]])

print(result)
# [[1, 4], [6, 10], [12], [14]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,14])
s.groupby(s.diff().ne(1).cumsum()).apply(lambda x: [x.iloc[0], x.iloc[-1]] if len(x) >= 2 else [x.iloc[0]]).tolist()
```

Outputs

```
[[1, 4], [6, 10], [12], [14]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

myarray = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,14]
sequences = np.split(myarray, np.array(np.where(np.diff(myarray) > 1)[0]) + 1)
l = []
for s in sequences:
    if len(s) > 1:
        l.append((np.min(s), np.max(s)))
    else:
        l.append(s[0])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4), (6, 10), 12, 14]
```